# Output Network Render not written automatically

Tags: add-on

I just discovered the Blender Network addon and after playing a little with it I am very happy with this functionality since now I can start renders from my MAC and have them executed on my Windows machine(s). However there is one little thing that does not seem to work (or maybe I am doing something wrong). When I submit a job the rendered frames are not written automatically. I have to click "Download render results from the network" in this panel

[image]

Is there a way to get the rendered frames written to disk without having to click this button ?

Comment: Note that this add-on may be buggy in recent versions, hasn't been updated for a while

Comment: is there a good alternative ?

Comment: not really, just some features may not work as expected and need workarounds

Comment: I did find a piece of software that provides some additions to the original network render addon like Gpu-rendering, which is pretty cool

Comment: Awesome! Do you have a link?

Comment: here is the link https://github.com/WARP-LAB/Blender-Network-Render-Additions